# xcode 5 cannot display large name in Bundle Display Name

Tags: ios, xcode

i have searched all the related questions and apple documentation but i didn't find an answer about displaying a large app name (with two lines of text) at desktop both on simulator or on iphone. Large app name means 15 chars which also means two lines of text. Can someone tell me if there is a setting so that the app name could be two lines instead of one. In case that i cannot change the max (11 chars) length can a place special characters in the name of the app

Thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't tried this but have you attempted to wrap a newline character in the string?

Comment: You could try filing a bug report with Apple. I have never seen an app with two lines but that doesn't mean it cannot happen.

Comment: i will search more and maybe i will do so